# How to make header component know if user is logged in in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React project that has a `HeaderComponent` that exists for all routes in project like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <FooterComponent />
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

And my problem is that the `<HeaderComponent>` is rendered when the website first loads but when the user logs in, the `<HeaderComponent>` is not aware of the changes because the component has already mounted.

So in my `<HeaderComponent>`, the `componentDidMount` function looks like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    AuthService.authorizeUser()
      .then((r) => {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      });
  }
```

This only works if I refresh the page.

Basically, if a user successfully logs in (from the `<Login>` component), what is the proper way of making my `HeaderComponent` aware of this?

Comment: create `AuthContext` wrap around your app

Comment: I have never done that, are there additional steps needed to use `AuthContext`?

Comment: I add an answer below. You can read the docs of how to create context for  you react app also there are a plenty of example of react context on some article

Comment: What is `AuthService.authorizeUser()`? Does it listen to changes in the auth status of a user? Using a React context may help, but the answer provided below doesn't appear to bridge the gap between providing the ***current*** auth status and "listening" for any changes to it. The listening to changes is IMHO the critical piece missing from both your code and the solution below using the Context API.

Comment: The authorizeUser function just pings the backend and returns true if the user is loggerIn/validated or false if they aren’t logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make `AuthContext` to share global state within your app:

```js
// AuthContext.js
export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({
  children,
}) => {
  // your context logic
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={yourAuthValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export const useAuth = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

// Layout.js
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

// Using `Outlet` to render the view within layout
export const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderComponent />
      <Outlet />
      <FooterComponent />
    </>
  )
}

// HeaderComponent.js
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext'

export const HeaderComponent = () => {
  // get state from auth context
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuth()

  return // rest of your code
}

// App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <-- Wrap your app with AuthContext let other components within your app can access auth state !-->
      <AuthProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
              <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I need although I don't understand it yet. Once I import `useAuth ` into the `Login` component, how do I actually set `isLoggedIn` to true?

Comment: And what is the purpose of Layout? I don’t see it used anywhere

Comment: `isLoggedIn` Its variable take from `auth` context (your need to learn context API first). Layout used in `router` and use `Outlet` to render your page view inside of layout. Probably your not ready to create complex app yet. Keep learn basic step by step you will gradually understand. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do so.
When you're facing a situation where you need to share the same state between multiple components, lifting the state up should be the first thing to try [Check this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-resonance-ssc3zj?file=/src/App.tsx).
And some great blogposts to read, [KCD - Prop Drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling), [KCD - State Management with React](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react)

Such approach may cause "prop drilling" when you need the same state in deeply nested components and that's where the context API comes in handy.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-glade-c738pp?file=/src/App.tsx)